# Cannot manage to remove $ pattern in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dput

I have a column in my dataset which looks like that (not the exact numbers) :

| Cost |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 75 |
| $ 1,789,456 |
| $ 1,200,923 |
| 690.3490200 |

The type of this column is character.

In order to do my computations i want to remove the "," the "$" and convert the column to numeric format.

```
df$cost<-gsub(",","",as.character(df$cost))
```

This one worked, i have now 1789456 instead of 1,789,456 etc. However, the code for the $ don't work

```
df$cost<-gsub("$","",as.character(df$cost))

df$cost<-gsub("$ ","",as.character(df$cost))
```

No error message but here's the output :

| Cost |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 75 |
| $ 1789456 |
| $ 1200923 |
| 690.3490200 |

Here's what the dput() gives me :

```
structure(list(head.df.cost..31. = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
4L, 1L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 11L
), .Label = c("$ 1062498", "115.11", "236.49", "275.87", "30", 
"40", "49", "50", "575.64", "60", "631.19200000000001", "75", 
"SPONSORED", "$ 2542196"
"ND", "USD 2300"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` represents the end of a line in regex. You need to escape it to use it as a literal. I'm not at a computer, but this should get you want you're looking for:

```
gsub("[ ,$]+", "", df$cost, perl = TRUE)
```

This should replace any one or more comma, space, or $. You don't have to escape `$` explicitly in square brackets. If you wanted to just replace `$`s, you could use the pattern `"\\$"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_number` from `readr`:

```
df = data.frame(cost = c("50", "75", "$ 1,789,456", "$ 1,200,923", "690.3490200"))
df$cost = readr::parse_number(df$cost)
```

Output:

```
df

         cost
1      50.000
2      75.000
3 1789456.000
4 1200923.000
5     690.349
```